# Query stuff result left join on multiple ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my SQL code

```
SELECT
    fu.Id,
    fu.DepartmentId,
    t.Name AS DepartmentName
FROM
    FactoryUser fu
LEFT JOIN
    Department t ON CAST(t.Id AS nvarchar(50)) IN (fu.DepartmentId)
WHERE
    fu.Id = 5619573199567804058
```

Result

```
Id      DepartmentId            DepartmentName
561957  519985,468063,502604    NULL
```

departmentId Associate department table
I hope query department name of all ids like "A-deptmentname,B-deptmentname,c-deptmentname"

```
Id      DepartmentId            DepartmentName
561957  519985,468063,502604    A-deptname,B-deptname,c-deptname
```

Comment: What is your version of SQL Server?

Comment: Looks like the problem is your design; you're storing delimited data in your database. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sql server 2012

Comment: @Larnu The old system did not do one-to-many design, but I need to solve the problem now

Comment: *"but I need to solve the problem now"* Then start fixing the design *now*. As an interim solution, however, I would suggest looking into (set based) string splitters but that isn't the solution, just a work around. As I said, fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: @Larnu I can't modify the data structure, I can only use sql to achieve this